# Notable Chess games where Results where a Double Forfeit (0/0)

Tags: arbiters, forfeit

Given the recent controversy with Dubov v Nepomniachtchi [link](https://chess.com/news/view/2023-fide-world-blitz-chess-championship-day-1) where the arbiter decided the result to be forfeited. Game Below

```
[FEN ""]
[Event "FIDE World Blitz Chess Championship 2023"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2023.12.29"]
[Round "11"]
[White "Dubov, Daniil"]
[Black "Nepomniachtchi, Ian"]
[Result "0-0"]
[WhiteElo "2763"]
[BlackElo "2795"]
[TimeControl "3+2"]

1. Nf3 Nf6 2. Nd4 Nd5 3. Nb3 Nb6 4. Nc3 Nc6 5. Ne4 Ne5 6. Ng5 Ng4 7. Nf3 Nf6 8. Ng1 Ng8 9. Nc5 Nc4 10. Na4 Na5 11. Nc3 Nc6 12. Nb1 Nb8
```

I recall a similar game between Tony Miles and Stewart Reuben where both players called it a draw before playing a single move. However I dont believe it got scored as 0/0.

There was also a notable game between Hikaru and Carlsen where they played a bong-cloud and three fold repetition the kinds for a draw. Again I believe the result for that was a draw.

Is this the first time a game has been forfeited in such a manner and if not can examples be provided?

Comment: Hübner. Oh, Robert Hübner. The Hübner doth protest too much, methinks. To my best knowledge the notorious drawn games against Miles and against Rogoff stood as draw, but any arbiter *could* have double forfeited both players on behalf of a prearranged result in both cases.